# Problems with nested forms and update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
....
  def update
    if @user.update(edit_user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Profilo aggiornato correttamente'
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end
....

  private
  def edit_user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, information_attributes: [:name, :surname, :date_of_birth, :address, :city, :country, :post_code, :phone])
  end
end
```

As all you can see I have nested forms.

The Informatation model is made by the following column:

- name
- surname
- date_of_birth
- address
- city
- country
- post_code
- phone
- **credit**

In the nested forms there is not an input field for the credit, because to update the credit I created another flow.

The problem is the following, when rails does `@user.update(edit_user_params)` it goes to overwrite all the columns of the Information row related to the particular user, that is, if the credit was 15$ after the update it becomes 0. What does that happen? Shouldn't the `update` method update only the columns pointed in `()`?

In addiction, because in the `Information.rb` I have the following validate:

`validates :credit, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01 }`

I always get an error because the `credit` field results equals to 0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before.  Here's the fix:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, information_attributes: [:id, :name, :surname, :date_of_birth, :address, :city, :country, :post_code, :phone])
```

You need to add :id to information_attributes.  I am not sure how secure it is (If you find out, please let me know), but it will fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, I worked it out adding in the model `User` the following: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :information, update_only: true`, that is I added the option `update_only: true`

Answer (score 0):

I somehow suspect that your edit_user_params function is getting in the way of this working.  Why not use validations in your user model, i.e. `validates :user, :presence => true` and then just pass params directly into the update statement?  Also, it might be helpful to see the code of your actual form.  What fields are in the form?